# Maris Ayin and bags from restaurants

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, marit-ayin, restaurant

Similar to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/208/1713), suppose there is a chain of restaurants that is mostly non-Kosher, but there happens to be one kosher franchise in the chain.  The example I am thinking of is that there is one kosher Dunkin Donuts near where I live, and many non-kosher ones. Is there a problem of Maris Ayin for me to publicly carry around a Dunkin Donuts bag from the kosher store?

If the answer to that is that there is no problem, what about if I pick up a donut on the way to a business trip out of town where there is no kosher Dunkin Donuts? May I carry the bag around there?

Comment: Rabbi Heinemann shlit'a is of the opinion that there's no maris ayin issue if they're not especially known for non-kosher stuff. So if enough people go into a Dunkin Donuts just for the coffee (do they?), that should address the concern. No? It is an issue, though. Two Atlanta rabbis spent ten minutes in a Dunkin shop drinking coffee and talking with the manager about going kosher, and by the end of the day half the town was wondering if it *was* kosher.

Comment: As a reminder, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Comment: I don't think DD is a problem, because you could have bought a coffee, or a bag of ground coffee, right? ...although I don't know if that can be generalized to *all restaurants*, though.

Comment: Extending your question - My neighborhood has about 8 kosher pizza stores. (Don't ask me why they need that many.) **Every** store's pizza boxes come from a non-kosher pizza place and say like "Giorgino's Pizza Palace". The side of the boxes have check boxes for toppings that include "bacon", "pepperoni", "Sausage", "Clam sauce" , "scungilli" etc. (OK, I know there are soy versions of these except for scungilli and clam sauce.) Is it marit ayin to walk out with a pie from one of these places?